# Ruby on Rails: How to TDD with javascript:void(0) route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to test my sign up form in the same way that [the tuturial do](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-tests_for_user_signup).

But in the tutorial the sign up page is a single page so no problem doing :

`visit signup_path`.

For me the sign form is a pop-up display via javascript :

`<%= link_to( "Inscrivez-vous !", "javascript:void(0)", id: "button-inscription" ) %>`

How can I simulate this using TDD in Ruby on Rails ?

Here is the button action when we press it :

```
$('#button-inscription').click(function() {

    showinscription();
});

function showinscription()
{
    document.getElementById("wrapper-inscription").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("bloc-inscription").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Here is my configurartion :

```
group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end
```

Here is my test for now :

```
  describe "signup form", js: true do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { click_link("button-inscription") }
    it { should have_content('Inscription') }
  end
```

In spec/spec_helper.rb I added :

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Those tests failed

Answer (score 0):

You would just do

```
page.click_link "Connexion"
```

Because your link is just triggering javascript, this requires that you be using a capybara driver capable of executing javascript (for example poltergeist). The default driver (rack test) won't handle this.

If you are using rspec then you can tag the spec as js and set `Capybara.javascript_driver` if you want to keep using the rack test driver for other specs (the main reason for this is speed)

Comment: Ok thanks for the method. I use `gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'` and `gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'`.Now my test failed because of javascript I guess even if I use `describe "signup form", js: true do` this is not supposed to work with this "option" ?

Comment: You should be able to get it to work, although it can be a little fiddly to get right first time around (eg you need to either turn of transactions or use complicated workarounds).

Comment: I tried to put `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in my `describe .... end` without success :/ Do you have any example ?